# Simple asynchronous operation implementation

Tags: c#, multithreading

Could you please see if they are no bugs in this implementation?  I am especially interested in knowing if there could be here any multithreading problems (such as race conditions).

It is written in C# for .NET 3.5.

```
public interface IAsyncOperation
{
    OperationToken Token { get; }
    bool IsCompleted { get; }
    Exception Exception { get; }
    bool Wait(int timeout);
}

public interface IAsyncOperation<out TResult> : IAsyncOperation
{
    TResult Result { get; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Asynchronous operation that may be executed on a separate thread.
/// IsCompleted and Exception would be synchronized after invoking Wait.
/// </summary>
public abstract class AsyncOperation : IAsyncOperation
{
    protected readonly object CompletionLock = new object();
    private volatile bool isCompleted; // volatile in order not to change the order of writing Exception and Result

    protected AsyncOperation(bool isCompleted = false)
    {
        IsCompleted = isCompleted;
        Token = OperationToken.New();
    }

    public OperationToken Token { get; protected set; }

    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        get { return isCompleted; }
        protected set { isCompleted = value; }
    }

    public Exception Exception { get; protected set; }

    public bool Wait(int timeout)
    {
        if (!IsCompleted)
        {
            lock (CompletionLock)
            {
                if (!IsCompleted)
                {
                    // when migrated to .NET 4.5 then implement with ManualResetEventSlim
                    Monitor.Wait(CompletionLock, timeout);
                }
            }
        }

        return IsCompleted;
    }

    protected void Complete()
    {
        if (IsCompleted)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The operation was already completed");
        }

        lock (CompletionLock)
        {
            if (IsCompleted)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The operation was already completed");
            }

            IsCompleted = true;
            Monitor.PulseAll(CompletionLock);
        }
    }

    protected void Complete(Exception exception)
    {
        if (!IsCompleted)
        {
            lock (CompletionLock)
            {
                if (!IsCompleted)
                {
                    Exception = exception;
                    IsCompleted = true;
                    Monitor.PulseAll(CompletionLock);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public abstract class AsyncOperation<TResult> : AsyncOperation, IAsyncOperation<TResult>
{
    protected AsyncOperation(bool isCompleted = false)
        : base(isCompleted)
    {
    }

    public TResult Result { get; private set; }

    protected void Complete(TResult result)
    {
        if (!IsCompleted)
        {
            lock (CompletionLock)
            {
                if (!IsCompleted)
                {
                    Result = result;
                    IsCompleted = true;
                    Monitor.PulseAll(CompletionLock);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Invokes the action on the ThreadPool.
/// </summary>
public class PooledOperation : AsyncOperation
{
    private readonly Action<OperationToken> action;
    private bool isStarted;

    public PooledOperation(Action<OperationToken> action)
    {
        this.action = action;
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Execute);
    }

    public static IAsyncOperation<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<OperationToken, TResult> function)
    {
        var result = new PooledOperation<TResult>(function);
        result.Start();
        return result;
    }

    public static IAsyncOperation Run(Action<OperationToken> action)
    {
        var result = new PooledOperation(action);
        result.Start();
        return result;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (!isStarted)
        {
            isStarted = ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Execute);
        }
    }

    private void Execute(object state)
    {
        try
        {
            action(Token);
            Complete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Complete(ex);
        }
    }
}

public class PooledOperation<TResult> : AsyncOperation<TResult>
{
    private readonly Func<OperationToken, TResult> function;

    public PooledOperation(Func<OperationToken, TResult> function)
    {
        this.function = function;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (!IsCompleted)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Execute);
        }
    }

    private void Execute(object state)
    {
        try
        {
            TResult result = function(Token);
            Complete(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Complete(ex);
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Used in own ThreadPool-like implementation.
/// </summary>
internal class AsyncCommand : AsyncOperation
{
    private readonly Action<OperationToken> command;

    public AsyncCommand(Action<OperationToken> command)
    {
        command.ThrowIfNull("command");
        this.command = command;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        if (IsCompleted)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The operation was already completed");
        }

        try
        {
            command(Token);
            Complete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Complete(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as you can tell, does the code seem to work as expected?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it is working fine.

Comment: Good! I was just making sure, since the site's scope isn't to *debug non-working code* (see [help/on-topic] for more info).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. For this:

   > ```
   > protected void Complete()
   > {
   >     if (!IsCompleted)
   >     {
   >         lock (CompletionLock)
   >         {
   >             if (!IsCompleted)
   >             {
   >                 IsCompleted = true;
   >                 Monitor.PulseAll(CompletionLock);
   >             }
   >         }
   >     }
   > }
   > ```

   I guess if a client/subclass calls `Complete()` twice it's an error in the client code. You may want to fail early and throw an exception. (*The Pragmatic Programmer: From Journeyman to Master* by *Andrew Hunt* and *David Thomas*: *Dead Programs Tell No Lies*.)

   Inverting the first condition and [using a guard clause](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/) also would make the code more flatten:

   ```
   protected void Complete()
   {
       if (IsCompleted)
       {
           throw new ...;
       }
       lock (CompletionLock)
       {
           if (IsCompleted)
           {
               throw new ...;
           }
           IsCompleted = true;
           Monitor.PulseAll(CompletionLock);
       }
   }
   ```

   You could extract a `CheckNotCompleted` method here to remove some duplicateion:

   ```
   protected void Complete()
   {
       CheckNotCompleted();
       lock (CompletionLock)
       {
           CheckNotCompleted();
           IsCompleted = true;
           Monitor.PulseAll(CompletionLock);
       }
   }

   private void CheckNotCompleted() 
   {
       if (IsCompleted)
       {
           throw new ...;
       }
   }
   ```
2. I'd consider using composition instead of inheritance. *Effective Java, Second Edition*, *Item 16: Favor composition over inheritance* is a good resource about that.
3. The code reminds me [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)s and [`Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)s from Java.

   In Java, you can create an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) with [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) (and with many other methods).

   ```
   int threadNumber = 1;
   ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadNumber);
   ```

   Then you can submit a `task` instance which implements [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) or [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) which will be run on another thread and you get a [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) instance immediately:

   ```
   Future future = executorService.submit(task);
   ```

   `Future` has `isDone()` and `get(timeout, timeUnit)` methods which are very similar to your `IsCompleted` and `Wait` methods.

   I feel that I've lost a little bit in the C# classes (I'm not too familiar with C#) but I hope the design of `Future` could give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for good comments!
1. I was thinking of it by my own and now I am sure that it is a good idea.
2. I agree with the concept but I do not know how I could implement it using composition with having good encapsulation (I do not want the `Complete` method to be public). I have subclasses that for example has an additional generic `TResult Result` property or implementation using Thread, ThreadPool, custom own ThreadPool. Do you want me to post more code for the review?

Comment: @Pellared: Feel free to share more code. `public` does not hurt, you can have an instance in a private field which is not known by any other class, so noone could call its public methods (so it's safe).

Comment: I have added the code. Thanks for involvement.

Comment: @Pellared: Answer updated, I hope it helps.